# How to access PHP variable from while function call in the next <?php?> tag for separate HTML?

Tags: php, mysql

How to access PHP variable from while(mysql_fetch_array($query)) function call in the next `<?php?>` tag for separate HTML?

```
<body>
<?php
    $sql="select * from $table order by id desc";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $id=$result[id];
    $subject=$result[subject];
    $subjectpic=$result[subjectpic];
    $content=$result[content];

    //global $id, $subject, $subjectpic, $content; ?
    }
?>
<div class="subject">
<?php
    print"$subject";
?>
</div>
<div class="subjectpic">
<?php
    print"$subjectpic";
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You find that in the manual here: http://php.net/language.variables.scope - If you have a problem to understand what a variable actually is, you find that here: http://php.net/variables. Also looping might be something new to you, no problem, while you have questions, answers are in the manual: http://php.net/control-structures.while .

Comment: In my answer below, I NEVER said that `while` block has a scope. Did I say that? The OP is trying to declare locally scoped variables in the `while {}` and trying to print them outside the closing brace!!

Comment: That code works as is. Of course, it only outputs the last row. You need to learn about quoting variables though: `print $subject;` and `$result['content'];`.

Comment: Hmm.. realized the folly. Edited my answer likewise... :)

Comment: Please note that the `mysql` extension is depreciated.

Comment: +1 for @hakre's comment above. I believe the OP is a newbie in PHP so I'd advise him/her to read up on the basics of scopes,variables and control structures of PHP first....

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your time, I'm a newbie in PHP, and I just can't find the answer in the manual, that's why I ask for some suggestion, and below arkascha's answer solve my problem.

Comment: The manual does not answer questions. It's just something to read. Start with the first page and read about the language, then for each page write some code on your own to reflect what you've learned.

Comment: @verisimilitude Thanks for reply, in the question I just don't know the brace can wrote in another php tag. And below arkascha's answer solve my problem.

Comment: @user1775888: That is also in the basic chapters: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can simply put the closing brace further down...

```
<body>
<?php
    $sql="select * from $table order by id desc";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $id=$result['id'];
      $content=$result['content'];
?>
  <div class="subject"><?php print $result['subject']; ?></div>
  <div class="subjectpic"><?php print $result['subjectpic']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

This version is more readable, though:

```
<body>
<?php
    $sql="select * from $table order by id desc";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $id=$result['id'];
      $content=$result['content'];
      sprintf('<div class="subject">%s</div>'."\n",    $result['subject']);
      sprintf('<div class="subjectpic">%s</div>'."\n", $result['subjectpic']);
    }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: 2nd is what I code before. The 1st is solve my question! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

just move the curly brace down

```
    //global $id, $subject, $subjectpic, $content; ?
?>
<div class="subject">
<?php
    print"$subject";
?>
</div>
<div class="subjectpic">
<?php
    print"$subjectpic";
?>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$subject` and the other variables print the values of the last row only. If you are planning to iterate over the values of the variables as you loop through the array consider printing/echoing them within the `while` block itself.

Comment: A while block has no local scope in PHP.

Comment: And database result sets must not have a last row.

Comment: @hakre: This time around, didn't get your point. Can you please elaborate?  I never mind the down-vote :)

Comment: *print the values of the last row only* - if the result has no last row (that is: zero rows), then no such values - that's all.

Comment: Oh. In that case there should be an appropriate code-check in place to handle that condition.. Nice catch anyway... :)